# Cannot read env file on Gatsby when using Docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gatsby

I have a problem with Docker, essentially I have created an .env file which is used by the frontend service like this:

```
  frontend:
    container_name: begreentannery_frontend
    build: 
      context: ./frontend/
      args: 
        API_URL: ${API_URL}
        MAILCHIMP_ENDPOINT: ${MAILCHIMP_ENDPOINT}
        FORM_KEY: ${FORM_KEY}
        GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID: ${GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID}
        GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID: ${GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID}
        FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID: ${FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID}
    ports:
      - '3001:80'
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

the backend service is actually a website maded with Gatsby. When I start the app doing `docker-compose up —build`  I can see that the variables are correctly passed in `gatsby-config`, eg:

```
console.log("API_URL:",process.env.API_URL)
```

but if I try to read the same variable in a component I get `undefined`.

How is that possible? Why I can read all the env variables inside `gatsby-config.js` but not in a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is that possible? Why I can read all the env variables inside
> `gatsby-config.js` but not in a component?

Because there are [server-side environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#server-side-nodejs) and [client-side environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#client-side-javascript). The first ones (server-side) are only available in the Node server (`gatsby-config.js`, `gatsby-node.js`, etc) while the seconds (client-side) only in the browser (the rest of the components, pages and templates).

To make an environment variable available to the browser, you need to prefix it with `GATSBY_` prefix, as the docs points:

> In addition to these Project Environment Variables defined in `.env.*`
> files, you could also define OS Env Vars. OS Env Vars which are
> prefixed with `GATSBY_` will become available in browser JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So I have to call the variable GATSBY_API_URL in the docker args?

Comment: Exactly. Give it a try.